# Flutter/Dart : How to initialize named parameter whose name doesn’t match the name of the field using initializing-formals

Tags: flutter, dart

https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#do-use-initializing-formals-when-possible

> You can’t always take advantage of it. Sometimes you want to have a
> named parameter whose name doesn’t match the name of the field you are
> initializing. But when you can use initializing formals, you should.

I found the above explanation, but what kind of code can I write to implement the above explanation?

If the "initializing formal's argument name" and the "field name" are different, an error will occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry.
This explanation says that "If we use initializing formal, "initializing formal's parameter name" and "field name" must be the same".